# Android: Rotate and size FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I have much more familiarity with the iOS world, so perhaps I'm missing some obvious, but here is my scenario and what I'm trying to accomplish. I have a custom view within a frame layout. This gets inflated within a fragment that is used in a couple different places, such as a linear layout. I want to be able to dynamically rotate the custom view 90 degrees and re-size it properly fill.

So I have the following frame layout (red) with custom view (white/content):
[image: original]

And I want this:
[image: rotate1]

I found it very trivial to rotate like this:
[image: rotate2]

However getting the stretching/scaling/translating I can't figure out. I've tried a variety of LayoutParams (size, margins, gravity, etc.) and can't get the magic right. I don't know if I'm just missing something simple, or if I'm totally going about things the wrong way.

Thanks.

UPDATE: original post was slightly wrong in my explanation

Answer (score 0):

So the FrameLayout is the parent of the CustomView (the CustomView is inside the FrameLayout)?
If so, **set a padding of e.g. 10dp to your FrameLayout**, and set the width and height property of your CustomView to:

> match_parent

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It made me realize that I was slightly incorrect in my original post. It's the custom view within the FrameLayout that needs to rotate, not the FrameLayout. My apologies.

Comment: That didn't seem to make any difference (aside from padding all the way around). I don't know if I'm doing something else wrong. And for the record, my rotation is done via:this.setPivotX(this.getWidth()/2);
this.setPivotY(this.getHeight()/2);
this.setRotation(90);